# How to test a ProtectedRoute with RTL

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom, react-testing-library

I am banging my head over the wall since too long.  I am not able to do a successful test for my ProtectedRoute component .

#### `protected-route.js` :

```
// src/components/protected-route/protected-route.js
import React from "react";
import { Outlet, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useAuth } from "../../utils/AuthContext.js";

const ProtectedRoute = () => {
  const { isAuthenticated, authStateFetched } = useAuth();

  if (!authStateFetched) {
    return null; // Render nothing until the authentication state has been fetched
  }

  if (!isAuthenticated) {
    return <Navigate to="/" replace={true} />;
  }

  return <Outlet />;
};

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

#### `AuthContext.js`

```
// src/utils/AuthContext.js
import { createContext, useContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";

const AuthContext = createContext();

export const useAuth = () => {
  return useContext(AuthContext);
};

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);
  const [authStateFetched, setAuthStateFetched] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchAuthState = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/is-authenticated");
        const data = await response.json();
        setIsAuthenticated(data.isAuthenticated);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching authentication state:", error);
      } finally {
        setAuthStateFetched(true);
      }
    };

    fetchAuthState();
  }, []);

  const login = () => {
    setIsAuthenticated(true);
  };

  const logout = () => {
    setIsAuthenticated(false);
  };

  const value = {
    isAuthenticated,
    authStateFetched,
    login,
    logout, // Added the 'logout' function here
  };

  return <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>;
};
```

#### `protected-route.test.js`

```
// src/components/protected-route/protected-route.test.js
import React from "react";
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import { MemoryRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import ProtectedRoute from "./protected-route";
import { AuthProvider, useAuth } from "../../utils/AuthContext.js";

jest.mock("../../utils/AuthContext.js");

const TestComponent = () => <div>Protected content</div>;

describe("ProtectedRoute", () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });

  test("renders protected content when authenticated", () => {
    useAuth.mockReturnValue({ isAuthenticated: true, authStateFetched: true });

    render(
      <AuthProvider>
        <MemoryRouter initialEntries={["/protected"]}>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/protected" element={<ProtectedRoute />}>
              <Route index element={<TestComponent />} />
            </Route>
          </Routes>
        </MemoryRouter>
      </AuthProvider>
    );

    expect(screen.getByText("Protected content")).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

#### error message

```
 ProtectedRoute
    × renders protected content when authenticated (25 ms)

  ● ProtectedRoute › renders protected content when authenticated

    TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element with the text: Protected content. This could be because the text is broken up by
multiple elements. In this case, you can provide a function for your text matcher to make your matcher more flexible.

    Ignored nodes: comments, script, style
    <body>
      <div />
    </body>

      30 |     );
      31 |
    > 32 |     expect(screen.getByText("Protected content")).toBeInTheDocument();
         |                   ^
      33 |   });
      34 | });
      35 |
```

#### Comments

As you can see, the `TestComponent` is not returned, I should have `Protected content` in the page.

#### Question

How to do a working test for my protected route

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mocking the response of the HTTP request is better. See [testing-recipes.html#data-fetching](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/testing-recipes.html#data-fetching)

> Instead of calling real APIs in all your tests, you can mock requests with dummy data. Mocking data fetching with “fake” data prevents flaky tests due to an unavailable backend, and makes them run faster.

E.g.

`protected-route.test.jsx`:

```
import React from "react";
import { render, screen, act } from "@testing-library/react";
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import { MemoryRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import ProtectedRoute from "./protected-route";
import { AuthProvider } from "./AuthContext";

const TestComponent = () => <div>Protected content</div>;

describe("ProtectedRoute", () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });

  test("renders protected content when authenticated", async () => {
    global.fetch = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({
      json: () => Promise.resolve({ isAuthenticated: true }),
    });

    await act(async () => {
      render(
        <AuthProvider>
          <MemoryRouter initialEntries={["/protected"]}>
            <Routes>
              <Route path="/protected" element={<ProtectedRoute />}>
                <Route index element={<TestComponent />} />
              </Route>
            </Routes>
          </MemoryRouter>
        </AuthProvider>
      );
    });

    expect(screen.getByText("Protected content")).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/76133719/protected-route.test.jsx
  ProtectedRoute
    ✓ renders protected content when authenticated (37 ms)

---------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File                 | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
---------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files            |   92.18 |    77.77 |   66.66 |   92.18 |                   
 AuthContext.jsx     |   93.33 |       80 |      60 |   93.33 | 20,30,34          
 protected-route.jsx |   89.47 |       75 |     100 |   89.47 | 13-14             
---------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.028 s
```

package versions:

```json
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",
"react-router-dom": "^6.8.1",
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
"@testing-library/react": "^14.0.0",
"jest": "^29.4.3",
```